# "Access of possibly undefined property buttonMode through a reference with static type Class" and other errors

Tags: actionscript

I'm making a quiz in flash for my tech class and I get that error, and "1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Class.". Here is my code

```
black_mc.buttonMode = true;
red_mc.buttonMode = true;
purple_mc.buttonMode = true;

black_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, feedback);
red_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, feedback);
purple_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, feedback);

function feedback(event:MouseEvent):void
{       if (event.target.name == "black_mc")
 {
      feedback_txt.text = "Bruh thats a black rectangle lmao";
 }
 else if(event.target.name=="red_mc")
 {
     feedback_txt.text = "You flaggin man thats a red square lolol";
     event.target.parent.removeChild(event.target);
 }
 else if(event.target.name=="purple_mc")
 feedback_txt.text = "Ayyyy you got it bruh!"
 event.target.parent.removeChild(event.target);
 }
```

I checked the linkage for all the symbols and they're fine. No idea why this error is there

Comment: Provided information is not enough for proper debugging. Please mention what those black_mc, red_mc and purple_mc are, where they are placed and where you are writing above code?

Comment: Essentially, the colour-mc's are the shapes. The black_mc is a black rectangle, purple_mc is a purple triangle, and red_mc is a red square. When you click on anything other than the purple_mc, a message should say incorrect or whatever my code says as feedback. When you click the purple_mc, you get a "correct" message.

Comment: Are they movie clips? Are they placed on the stage before script execution? BTW: your feedback function has some typos. Look at last else if statement, you are missing semicolon. Make sure you want last removeChild to be executed every time.

Comment: try using the `trace` statement to see if black_mc, red_mc and purple_mc are indeed movieClips.

Comment: Error suggests you are applying it directly to the class itself rather than some instance (var) of the class... Is `black_mc` the actual **linkage** name? if yes then try `var mc_blk : black_mc = new black_mc();` then `addChild(mc_blk)` now check if `mc_blk.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, feedback);` gives an error... You can un-comment the other addEvents with a `//` in front of each of those lines, so they do not cause errors during the test.